# Laravel 5 Route group controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Now I am writing routes like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2/'], function(){
    Route::post('/reg', 'UserController@reg');
    Route::post('/login', 'UserController@login');
    ...
});
```

Is there any way to make routes like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2/'], function(){
    Route::group(['uses' => 'UserController'], function(){
        Route::post('/reg', '@reg');
        Route::post('/login','@login');
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, but you could do this

```
Route::controller('v2', 'UserController');
```

So now you should have in your controller methods `getReg`, and `postLogin` and they would be at same routes as you described.

```
GET /v2/reg -> UserController@getReg
POST /v2/login -> UserController@postLogin
```

Comment: How to add middleware ?

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#defining-middleware and 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#registering-middleware
This should be useful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Implicit Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers) instead.

Your controller method names should begin with the HTTP verb they respond to followed by the URI you want.

**For example: `postLogin` method will respond to `POST /login`.**

```
Route::controller('v2', 'UserController', [
   'postReg' => 'user.reg',
   'postLogin' => 'user.login',
]);
```